# Binding model with migation in RoR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would have a question about models and migrations in rails.

Let's take an example. I have a Member model :

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :a, :b
end
```

And the corresponding migration :

```
class CreateMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :members do |t|
            t.string :a
            t.string :b
        end
    end
end
```

I realize later that a Member has a Car. So, I have to create the Car model etc ...
Now, I have to modify both models adding `belong_to` and `has_one` rules but also create a new migration and add `car.integer :member_id`

I find it pretty unpractical and redundant. Is there any trick letting do this automatically ? Furthermore, unlike Symfony2 where model are totally dissociated from the database, here we need to inform a foreign_key column. Is there any way to write something like `car.member :member` instead of `car.integer :member_id` ? It is a detail, but I would appreciate.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Rails provides some smart generators:

Try:

```
rails g model car member:references
```

This would automatically generate complete migrations with the member_id as a foreign key (even with an index) and the `belongs_to :member` line is also already added to the `Car` class.

`rails g model car member:references` generates this:

```
class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cars do |t|
    t.references :member

    t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :cars, :member_id
  end
end
```

and this:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

So the only thing left to do is adding the line `has_one :car` to the `Member` class.

For more on generators see: [A Guide to The Rails Command Line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate)

Comment: Ok, but how can I do this if I already generated my Car model and I want to update it ?

Comment: In that case I'm also clueless. Sorry. But when generating migrations you can add some flags to automatically add the columns to you migration file like this: `rails g migration add_member_id_to_cars member_id:integer`, but you might be doing that already =).